# SMS verification NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sms

I'am building a blog with `NodeJS`, `Express` and `MongoDB`, its a simple REST API where I can post blogs, signup, login, etc.

I want to build a SMS verification system using twilio, which is pretty easy, generate some CODE, send it to user phone number with twilio and when user post to `/verify`, I'm checking the code and update the user.

My problem is that I'm not sure where to store the generated code.
From what I searched I can do the following ways:

1. Store the code in User model (`user.verificationCode = GENERATED_CODE`)
2. Store the code in user session
3. Make a new model called code and save it `{ user: ObjectId(USER_ID), code: GENERATED_CODE }`

But I'm not sure if this is best practice, can someone explain whats the best way do to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 does not make any sense.   and to go for option 1 or option 2 depends on how long you can wait for user to enter the  code. and what is the life of your session. Whether your session is going to expire on browser close or not?

Generally I suggest to **go for option 2**. assuming that user is going to feed back the code before your session expires. which is typical case.